# Is it possible to access the 'Releases' Tag via PyGithub?

Tags: python, api, github-api, pygithub

I try to navigate to the releases tag of a specific repository in Github via the PyGithub API. I only can navigate to the repository, but I can't navigate any further. Is there a command in the PyGithub API?

**UPDATE**

Or is there another Python API that satisfies my demands?

Comment: Can't you filter through the tags you get from this call? http://pygithub.readthedocs.org/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_tags

Comment: yes but there I only can access the `zipball_url` and the `tarball_url` of one Tag. But I can't access executables if there are some, like [here](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/releases/tag/v0.6.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen a lot of the python-based github client libraries don't have support for all of the github api endpoints, including releases. However, the github3 library does on its master branch. Install it with `pip install https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/zipball/master`

Here's a functional example of its usage:

```
from github3 import GitHub
gh = GitHub()
releases = gh.repository("github", "git-lfs").iter_releases()
for release in releases:
  for asset in release.assets:
    print "Release %s: %s" % (release.name, asset.name)
```

Comment: is there a possibility via github3 api to filter the coding languages, e.g. to get only the repositories coded in C or Python?